# My MKV to MP4 converted video doesn't play in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, video, ffmpeg, video-player

I am stuck on one issue from last 1 day. I am using Adobe flex video display to play video for my site.

There is some converted video from MKV to MP4 using ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i Test.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy Test.mp4
```

Now, i am trying to play that video from local it's working fine. But when i upload that video on server and trying to play video. Then it will not work with flex `VideoDisplay`  same will work in browser and HTML videoplayer and also works with JWPlayer.

Other mp4 video which are not converted works very fine. Only converted Videos are not working in only flex VideoDisplay.

I am Just playing using.

```
<s:VideoDisplay id="videoDisp" autoPlay="false" autoDisplayFirstFrame="true" />
```

And give path to `videoDisplay` like:

```
videoDisp.source = Video_path;
```

My video file Video and Audio codec is as shown in below image:

[image]

Any help will be appreciate, 
Thanks.

Comment: Flash player can play only two video formats : FLV (H263, VP6) and MP4 (H264), so if your video is not supported, you have to convert it again if you want to play it with Flash Player.

Comment: @akmozo My video file is mp4 and codec is as i given in image. it's h264

Comment: If your video is supported, you should may be show us your code to know more about the problem.

Comment: @akmozo I edited my code. I am just using VideoDiplay nothing else. And it will play other MP4 files which are not converted from MKV.

Comment: Could you provide a working video and the one that present the problem, I'll test them both. And which kind of stream are you using ? A HTTP I think ?

Comment: @akmozo Here http://www.filedropper.com/ironman is the file which is not played. All other mp4 file which i download directly as a mp4 not "mkv and convert to mp4" are working.

Comment: Are you trying to play your video from a remote server or a local one ?

Comment: @akmozo From remote server in local it's working.

Comment: @akmozo And another thing i am going to told which i check recently is that small video is played in my player after i put that link ideal for more than 20-30 minute. and it's played after around 30 minute. it's length is 2:30 minute.

Comment: You should show the complete console output instead of just a segment, and you shoukd copy and paste it as text instead of an image. The text shows the whole thing, is easier to read, is searchable, and isn't reliant on the reliability of a (third party?) image host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my first tests, I saw an #2032 error, which is a stream error, and I think it's caused by the size of your video, because Flash player is trying to download the whole video before starting playing it, and I think there is a timeout or something like that which fire that error. So to avoid that, you can use [qt-faststart](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/11/12/how-to-make-mp4-progressive-with-qt-faststart/) to move metadata and offset information to the front of the file which will help to play it more quickly.

You can download that tool from [here](http://multimedia.cx/eggs/improving-qt-faststart/) or if you are a fun of python you can try it from [here](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/qtfaststart). I will also upload a copy [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/5f9cuhubyhvfth2/qt-faststart-git-91a4abd8-win64.7z) for Win64.

[image]

Hope that can help.

Comment: I can use that in flex?

Comment: @ketan No, it's a command tool, like ffmpeg, to execute with your mp4 video : `qtfaststart.exe input.mp4 output.mp4` and then you can use your video ( the output of course ).

Comment: Thanks. I am using AIR version. Lets i am checking it.

Comment: Sorry But it will take same time to play video. It will load whole video and then play. I just convert video and from new converted file rename file name and upload to live server and play.

Comment: @ketan Don't use the same name of the video file, and try to remove the cache of your browser or try another one.

Comment: Sorry, not successed. will you please convert that file which i given to you. And How can i use that with command line.

Comment: @ketan I tested all that before putting my answer. You can download the video from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/watch/pnbqk33575imvwy/IronMan_fast.mp4).

Comment: You can use `ffmpeg` instead of `qt-faststart`. Example: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4`.