# web recorded video not played in ipad

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, video, actionscript, ffmpeg

I record video from web using flash media server. Now using flex default player i tried to play video but, it will not play ipad.(ios device) 
I checked that video codec and it is something like following:

```
libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 92.100 / 52. 92.100
  libavcodec     55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
  libavformat    55. 45.100 / 55. 45.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavfilter     4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[flv @ 0000000002b60220] Stream discovered after head already parsed
Input #0, flv, from 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\123654789.flv':
  Metadata:
    canSeekToEnd    : false
    createdby       : FMS 4.5
    creationdate    : Tue Jun 30 16:27:22 2015
  Duration: 00:00:15.25, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 52 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: flv1, yuv420p, 320x227, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: speex, 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 20 kb/s
    Stream #0:2: Data: none
```

I record video following ways:

```
netstream.publish("FILENAME","record");
```

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Another flv file i got which is played in ios. But when i check it's codec it something like following:

```
r --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab -
-enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx
--enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-
libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 92.100 / 52. 92.100
  libavcodec     55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
  libavformat    55. 45.100 / 55. 45.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavfilter     4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, flv, from 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\16402.flv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : 3gp4
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    encoder         : Lavf55.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:13.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 304 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: flv1, yuv420p, 320x240, 300 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 1k tbn
, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, mono, s16p, 0 kb/s
```

How, can i record/convert flv like below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a normal behavior that iPAD didn't play your FLV video because simply it's not supported by iOS, as mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html) by Apple :

> iOS supports many industry-standard video formats and compression standards, including the following:
>
> - H.264 video, up to 1.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Low-Complexity version of the H.264 Baseline Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
> - H.264 video, up to 768 Kbps, 320 by 240 pixels, 30 frames per second, Baseline Profile up to Level 1.3 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
> - MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats

Hope that can help.

Comment: so what can i do to play video that video in iPad . It there any another option.

Comment: @ketan You have to convert it to a supported format by iOS.

Comment: how can i convert in flex? Also check my edited question

Comment: @ketan No, flex can not do that ! You can use, for example, [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) and you can find many tutorials for that like [this one](http://www.robotgoblin.co.uk/blog/2012/05/26/converting-videos-for-ipod-using-ffmpeg/) ...

Comment: @ketan I think that your second video is a 3gp4 ( can contain a MPEG-4 video, take a look [here](http://www.ftyps.com/3gpp.html) ) with mp3 for audio, so it's possible to be played by iOS.

Comment: plus 1 for your answer and now i got video playable but take much time to play video.

Comment: @ketan I think that we have already discussed this behavior in one of your old question and I answered you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29233688/2256820). You can use `qtfaststart` or `movflags=+faststart` option in your ffmpeg command.

Comment: Ohh yes i think same behavior and solution here.

Answer (score 0):

You should transcode it into H.264 mp4 stream on Flash Media Server and feed that stream into your flex application. If you record the video by Adobe Live Video Encoder there is an option to set the output format either. I did that a few years ago.

Comment: There's no way to do that, iOS does not support flv, that's why Flash Media Server will automatically convert the video to iOS supported stream.

Comment: Check in my question. second flv video i got from somewhere are supported and played very well. Check it codec in my question.